# Grid View Scroller

Tags: android, gridview, scroller

I am new to Andriod, I have n of TextView inside the GridView, which comes with its own scroller, I need a method which tell whether a particular View in the GridView is Visible in the View Port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use one of the adapter methods: refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29)

> > public int getFirstVisiblePosition ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 Returns the
>   position within the adapter's data set
>   for the first item displayed on
>   screen. Returns The position within
>   the adapter's data set

Comment: Thanks for your timely help. getFirstVisiblePosition () returns the first position viewable in the viewport getPositionForView(view) will return the position for your view. For your view to be viewable in the viewport of the scroller it should have a greater value then the value returned by the getFirstVisiblePosition ().